# sed replace group of files string

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed, spaces

I am trying to replace a string in multiple lines.  It is late and I'm getting restless, maybe someone would prefer to give it a shot for some SO points. The string I'm replacing is 'STORED AS TEXTFILE' from the SQL below...

```
PARTITIONED BY(load string, date string, source_file string)
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '${staging_directory}/${tablename}';
```

And to make it look like...

```
PARTITIONED BY(load string, date string, source_file string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '${staging_directory}/${tablename}';
```

So my expression is

```
:%s/)\nSTORED AS TEXTFILE\nLOCATION '/)\rROW FORMAT DELIMITED \rFIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' \rSTORED AS TEXTFILE \rLOCATION '/g
```

Which works inside the file (with vim) but I can't get it to work with one command on all of the files in the directory.  I've tried so far...

```
sed -i "s/)\nSTORED AS TEXTFILE\nLOCATION '/)\rROW FORMAT DELIMITED \rFIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' \rSTORED AS TEXTFILE \rLOCATION '/g"
```

... and I also tried the above statement with all the spaces escaped.  Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***gawk*** *in-place editing* approach - available since GNU awk 4.1.0:

```
gawk -i inplace '$0~/STORED AS TEXTFILE/{ $0="ROW FORMAT DELIMITED" ORS "FIELDS TERMINATED BY \047,\047" ORS $0 }1' file*
```

- `-i inplace` - *in-place* editing of each input file

Comment: what *Usage message*?

Comment: Usage: gawk [POSIX or GNU style options] -f progfile [--] file ...
Usage: gawk [POSIX or GNU style options] [--] 'program' file ...
POSIX options:          GNU long options:
        -f progfile             --file=progfile
        -F fs                   --field-separator=fs
        -v var=val              --assign=var=val

Comment: what's your OS?

Comment: It is CentOS 6.8

Comment: @Mike, got it. I should have mentioned that in-place extension available since GNU awk 4.1.0, added a note to the answer. https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=gawk

Answer (score 1):

sed processes file line by line following link gives a solution for multiline processing https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26284/how-can-i-use-sed-to-replace-a-multi-line-string

otherwise in perl the default input line separator `$/` can be changed or undefined (read whole file):

```
perl -i.BAK -pe 'BEGIN{undef$/}s/.../.../g' file
```

After reading comments on accepted answer of link, GNU sed has the `-z` option which does quite the same uses NUL character as line delimiter (`$\="\0"`), whereas `undef $/` uses no delimiter.